# Why is hashset showing strange behavior?

Tags: java, if-statement, hashset

I am trying to code a simple problem. Just for the clarification its, not an ongoing contest.
Here is the code

```
    package Algorithms;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class shino {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        int seq[]= new int[a];
        int count=0;
        for(int j=0;j<a;j++){
            seq[j] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        HashSet<HashSet> hashSets = new HashSet<>();


            for(int y=0;y<seq.length;y++){

                for(int u=0;u<seq.length;u++){

                    HashSet<Integer> hash = new HashSet<>();
                    int q =Math.abs(y-u);
                    if(y!=u && q==1 ) {

                        hash.add(seq[y]);
                        hash.add(seq[u]);
                    }
                    if(hashSets.add(hash)){
                        System.out.println(seq[y]+" "+seq[u]);
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println(count);

    }
}
```

Now as you can see there is a condition of **y!=u** but still when i give the input as

```
5
1 2 3 4 5
```

The output it yealds

```
1 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
5
```

Why is there a double **1 1** at top?
I am not really getting what i am doing wrong here?
To be honest, i do have some programming exp, but i really can't figure out why is this happening?

Comment: You're first adding the empty HashSet and only one of these is allowed. Your 2nd if block is not good, and instead that should all be within the first if block.

Comment: oh yes..!!!, how did this thing escape :-(, Do write the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're first adding the empty HashSet, and only one is allowed suggesting that your second if boolean test is no good:

```
HashSet<Integer> hash = new HashSet<>();
int q =Math.abs(y-u);
if(y!=u && q==1 ) {
    hash.add(seq[y]);
    hash.add(seq[u]);
}
if(hashSets.add(hash)){
    System.out.println(seq[y]+" "+seq[u]);
    count++;
}
```

Instead put all in the first if block:

```
HashSet<Integer> hash = new HashSet<>();
int q = Math.abs(y-u);
if(y != u && q == 1 ) {
    hash.add(seq[y]);
    hash.add(seq[u]);

    System.out.println(seq[y] + " " + seq[u]);
    count++;
}
```

Note: why test if `y != u` at all, since if `q == 1`, y **cannot** equal u

so better still:

```
if (q == 1) {
    hash.add(seq[y]);
    hash.add(seq[u]);

    System.out.println(seq[y] + " " + seq[u]);
    count++;
}
```

Comment: yes, i just added that, q==1, was checking something.

Comment: Forgot to remove that. My bad, such a silly ques :-( and thanx